# Diagonalizable vs Normal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have real valued matrix $A$, are these two notions of being Diagonalizable and being Normal equivalent?

Comment: No. Any normal matrix is diagonalizable. The converse is not true.

Comment: @Artem Isn't $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ a Normal matrix that isn't diagonalizable over the reals?

Comment: @CalvinLin, the usual meaning is "diagonalizable over the complex".

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't necessarily agree that is true. Furthermore, there have been people who argue that since OP specified real-valued, he is working with the reals as the base field. In any case, the real version is still slightly interesting to understand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A real matrix is diagonalizable (over $\mathbb{C}$) by a *unitary* matrix if and only if it is normal.

But there are non-normal matrices that can be diagonalized by non-unitary matrices. For instance

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\\2 & 1\end{array}\right] = PDP^{-1}$$
where 
$$P = \left[\begin{array}{cc} -1 & 1\\ 1& 2\end{array}\right]$$
 and 
$$D=\left[\begin{array}{cc} -1 &0\\0 & 2\end{array}\right].$$

Comment: Then what's the geometrical meanings of real diagonalizable matrices and real normal matrices?