# Geometrical meanings of diagonalizable and normal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, geometric-interpretation

We know that normal matrices are diagonalizable, but the converse is not true. For example, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271869/diagonalizable-vs-normal). Since a diagonalizable matrix represents a scaling operation under certain basis, so I wonder what additional geometrical meanings a normal matrix processes to be distinguished from other diagonalizable matrices. In other words, how to geometrically interpret matrices that can be diagonalized by unitary and non-unitary matrices? Thanks!

Comment: Diagonalizing Matrix for Normal matrices is a orthogonal matrix. Orthogonal matrices represent rotation. Thus Normal matrices first rotates your vector to their co-ordinate system (given by the columns), then scales the components of rotated vector, and then rotates it back. Note that this co-ordinate system is also orthogonal. But for other matrices, the co-ordinate system in which scaling happens is not a orthogonal co-ordinate system.

Comment: @dineshdileep, I wonder if "orthogonal matrix/matrices" in your description should be relaxed to "unitary matrix/matrices".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, eigenvectors are the axes where there is a magnification/contraction.

For normal matrices, these axes are orthogonal to each other, 
thus, a matrix is normal if and only if it represents a linear transform 
that scales the coordinate axes, (in a suitable chosen orthogonal basis).

A diagonalizable matrix in general is a similar linear transform,
(scaling of the coordinate axes), but the basis need not to be orthogonal.

Comment: So is a non-diagonalizable matrix that has, for example, ones in the first super-diagonal in its Jordan form, represented by a linear transform and that added affine component?

Comment: That sounds correct.