# Diagonal matrix is normal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, hermitian-matrices

Suppose $A$ is a diagonal matrix. I want to show that $A$ is normal. That is: $A^* A = A A^* $. Since $A$ is diagonal, then $A = A^*$ and so $A$ is trivially normal. IS this correct? or I am missing something?

Comment: Your matrix is real  , right ?

Comment: not necesarilly

Comment: For example, note that
$$
\pmatrix{i\\&i}^* = \pmatrix{-i\\&-i}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is real, then you're right.

If $A$ is complex, then $A$ is not the same as $A^*$.

In any case, $A^* A = A A^*$ because $A^* A$ and $A A^*$ are diagonal matrices with entries $\overline a_{ii} a_{ii}=a_{ii} \overline a_{ii}$.

Comment: if $A$ is complex and diagonal, does it still hold that $A$ must be normal ?

Answer (score 3):

It is not true that $A=A^{\ast}$ is general; this is true if and only if $A$ is real.

In multiplying diagonal matrices all that happens is multiplying the diagonal elements pairwise. This is obviously commutative, so multiplication of diagonal matrices is commutative.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: It is true for any matrix that, $A$ is normal if and only if $A$ is diagonalizable right??

Comment: @FareedAF No; any normal matrix is diagonalizable, but not every diagonalizable matrix is normal. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271869/diagonalizable-vs-normal) for details.