# Are all non-defective matrices normal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

All normal matrices are non-defective, but are all non-defective matrices normal? I haven't been able to find anything about this online, so presumably it is not true. If this is so, could someone provide an example of a non-defective, non-normal matrix? Otherwise, a pointer towards a proof would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 2\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Isn't that the same question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271869/diagonalizable-vs-normal

Comment: @A.Γ.Indeed it is. Apologies. I was thinking about linear independence of eigenvectors and missing the absolutely obvious point that this is equivalent to diagonalisability.

Comment: @A.Γ.Would it be appropriate to close or delete the question?